# (Java) Simple File Transfer (Client-Server) with Socket

Tags: java, sockets, networking, client-server, stream-socket-client

I'm working in an simple File Transfer program but I really get a point where is impossible to continue, cause the compiler give the following error:

> Cliente_FTP.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
>                 conexion.enviar_archivo(nombre_archivo);  //    THIS IS THE LINE GENERATING THE ERROR !!!
>                         ^   symbol:   method enviar_archivo(String)   location: variable conexion of type Misocket 1 error

I'm just trying to create a new method (enviar_archivo and recibir_archivo) in a package (Misocket) but it seams that is not reachable when this is called.. I will try to explain me better showing the code, firts I have a Client side with interchange the log and password with the server, and until here everythng goes well, but when I try to call in method enviar_archivo in the class Misocket and compile, I got the error above. Please if some of you see what I'm doing bad please let me know.

This is the Client whos call the clases Misocket that is a Socket extention.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;    
import Misocket.*;

public class Cliente_FTP {

    static String log;
    static String clave;
    static String nomb;
    static String direccion;
    Socket servidor;
    int numCliente=0;
    static String mensaje;


 public static void main(String args[]) {

        direccion = "localhost";
        int puerto = 5972;
        String operacion = null;
        String nombre_archivo;

        try {
            Misocket conexion = new Misocket(direccion, puerto);
            System.out.println(conexion.recibir_mensaje());
            boolean bandera_operacion;
            bandera_operacion = true;

            while(bandera_operacion){
                operacion = System.console().readLine("Ingrese (1) autenticar usuario o (2) para registar usuario: ");
                if(operacion.equals("1")){
                    System.out.println("autenticar usuario");
                    bandera_operacion = false;

                }
                else if (operacion.equals("2")) {
                    System.out.println("registrar usuario");
                    bandera_operacion= false;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("error");
                    bandera_operacion = true;
                }
            }

            log = System.console().readLine("usuario: ");
            clave = System.console().readLine("clave: ");

            mensaje = operacion + " " + log + " " + clave;
            conexion.enviar_mensaje(mensaje);


            mensaje = conexion.recibir_mensaje();
            System.out.println(mensaje);

            if(!"Usuario no existente".equals(mensaje)){  // si el usuario si existe ejecutar codigo para transferir archivos
                System.out.println("listo para transmitir archivos");
                nombre_archivo = "ENVIAR+ARCHIVO" + "./FTP/ArchivoServidor.txt";
                conexion.enviar_archivo(nombre_archivo);  //    THIS IS THE LINE GENERATING THE ERROR !!!

            }

            conexion.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
}
```

the class Misocket that contain the method to create socket, streams , send an receive messages, everything goes well but the methos that should send and receive Files:
package Misocket;

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Misocket extends Socket{

    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader entrada;
    private PrintStream salida;
    private InputStream is;
    private OutputStream os;
    private String nombre_archivo;


    public Misocket(String host_servidor, int puerto) throws SocketException, IOException{
        socket = new Socket(host_servidor, puerto);
        crear_flujos();
    }

    public Misocket(Socket socket) throws IOException{
        this.socket = socket;
        crear_flujos();
    }


    private void crear_flujos() throws IOException {        
        InputStream flujoentrada = socket.getInputStream();
        entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(flujoentrada));
        OutputStream flujosalida = socket.getOutputStream();
        salida = new PrintStream (flujosalida);
    } // FIN CREAR_FLUJOS


    public void enviar_mensaje(String mensaje) throws IOException {
        if(mensaje.contains("ENVIAR+ARCHIVO")){
            nombre_archivo = mensaje.replaceAll("ENVIAR+ARCHIVO", "");
            System.out.println("enviando " + nombre_archivo);
            enviar_archivo(nombre_archivo);
        } else {
            System.out.println("estoy como mensaje" + nombre_archivo);
            salida.println(mensaje);
            salida.flush();
        }

    } // FIN ENVIAR MENSAJE


    public String recibir_mensaje() throws IOException {
        String mensaje = entrada.readLine();
        return mensaje;
    } // FIN RECIBIR_MENSAJE


    public void enviar_archivo(String nombre_archivo) throws IOException {
        File archivo = new File(nombre_archivo);
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) archivo.length() + 1];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(archivo);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        System.out.println("Sending " + "(" + mybytearray.length + " bytes)");
        salida.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
        salida.flush();
        fis.close();
        bis.close();
    } // FIN ENVIAR ARCHIVO

    public void recibir_archivo() throws IOException{
        int filesize = 6022386;
        int bytesRead;
        int current = 0;
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[filesize];

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("def");
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        current = bytesRead;

        do {
            bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, current,
                    (mybytearray.length - current));
            if (bytesRead >= 0)
                current += bytesRead;
        } while (bytesRead > -1);

        bos.write(mybytearray, 0, current);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
    }

    public void cerrar() throws IOException {
        socket.close();
    } // FIN CERRAR SOCKET
} // FIN DE LA CLASE
```

Regards
/Russo

Comment: You shouldn't need to extend for Socket, you're not really adding any new functional to the socket class itself...

Comment: And you *certainly* don't need to *both* extend Socket *and* have a Socket member variable. Re your compilation error, I really expect programmers to be able to sort them out for themselves in most cases.